# Angular component ng-content passing template with dynamic output placeholders

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular2-ngcontent

Is it possible to have a component that can handle dynamic  projection like this?

```
<my-component [date]="2022-03-22">
   <p>This date falls on a <strong #dayName></strong>! It is on week number <span #weekNum></span> of year <span #year></span>.</p>
</my-component>
```

The HTML code passed into the component has a few ElementRef placeholders for outputting the day name, week number and year based on the date provided in the component @Input.

My roadblock now is `my-component` fails to detect the `ElementRef`s when I tried to access them like this:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'my-component'
})
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {

   @ViewChild('dayName') elemDayName!: ElementRef;
   @ViewChild('weekNum') elemWeekNum!: ElementRef;
   @ViewChild('year') elemYear!: ElementRef;

   ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.elemDayName.nativeElement.innerHTML = 'Tuesday';
      this.elemWeekNum.nativeElement.innerHTML = 12;
      this.elemYear.nativeElement.innerHTML = 2022;
   }
}
```

Is something like this doable or am I using a wrong method to accomplish this functionality?

Comment: If you want to project some content inside another content, you can go for `ng-content` (see [doc](https://angular.io/guide/content-projection)). But for the data sharing, I would rather opt for a shared service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone's looking, I managed to solve it this way:

#### Parent component

```
<my-component [date]="2022-03-22">
   <p>This date falls on a <strong #dayName></strong>! It is on week number <span #weekNum></span> of year <span #year></span>.</p>
</my-component>
```

#### my-component.ts

```
@Component({
   selector: 'my-component'
})
export class MyComponent implements AfterContentInit {

   @Input() date: string;

   @ContentChild('dayName') elemDayName!: ElementRef;
   @ContentChild('weekNum') elemWeekNum!: ElementRef;
   @ContentChild('year') elemYear!: ElementRef;

   ngAfterContentInit() {

      /* do any custom processing as needed and update the template using innerHTML */

      this.elemDayName.nativeElement.innerHTML = 'Tuesday';
      this.elemWeekNum.nativeElement.innerHTML = 12;
      this.elemYear.nativeElement.innerHTML = 2022;
   }
}
```

#### my-component.html

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, @ViewChild can only be used to access elements that are declared in the component's own template. I suggest you use other Angular features like creating other components, or directives, etc. and use a common Service among all these elements to share the information passed in the @Input parameter.